Where can I place a fire near my bed to gain the benefits but not suffer from the smoke?
Having a bed near a fire has benefits, but I have difficulty placing the fire and bed efficiently.
When the fire is not covered with a roof, it is extinguished when it rains.
When the fire is indoors, the smoke drifts into the house.
What is a good setup for a house with a fire and beds? How do the mechanics work? For example, is it enough to have the fire in a x meter range from the bed, no matter the walls or vertical distance?

Coming from the main SE homepage ("Hot Questions"), the title of this question really concerned me until I noticed what community this was in.

You can use rooftop parts that are open on the sides, and place these at the ends of the ridge beam, or build a chimney with them. The goal is to have any kind of hole covered from above in the apex of the roof, optimally directly above the fireplace.
The smoke will gather underneath the ridge and make its way out through any holes present.
A single smoke entity is 0.42 m in diameter, and requires a gap of about one meter to escape. Depending on the type of fire and the mount placed, more space might be necessary to guarantee an uninterrupted flow.
See Valheim Wiki's Smoke entry for more details.

For example, you can place the 45° thatch roof ridge depicted below on four wood poles above a hole in your roof. Or simply use these to end the roof ridge without filling them up with boards afterwards.

Some more inspiration:










image source
image source
image source







image source
image source





In very tall dwellings, you can even opt to build a chimney upwards above the fireplace, leaving a little space for the light and warmth to go through:

image source

Finally, according to someone on Reddit, you can even build a smoke room, and no chimney will be necessary:

How about no chimney? The smoke will disappear eventually after like 6m so you can just build a smoke room in the attic.

To be more precise, according to the aforementioned Wiki,

smoke starts disappearing after 60 seconds. However there is also a total limit of 100 smoke instances. When exceeded, the oldest ones start instantly disappearing.
Disappearing smoke is removed after 2 seconds.

